# Автообновление ListView с сохранением позиции скролла

Tags: java, android

Скажите пожалуйста, что не так? Обновляю ListView хандлером каждые 15 сек. Но при каждом обновлении, позиция скролла сбрасывается на 0. Я так понимаю что нужно обновлять данные адаптера, но как это правильно реализовать?

```
class MessageLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CHAT_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, response);

                    JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
                    try {
                        dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray chat = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("chat");

                        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < chat.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject chatList = chat.getJSONObject(i);

                            String us_id = chatList.getString("us_id");
                            String name = chatList.getString("name");
                            String txt = chatList.getString("text");

                            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            map.put(LV_USID, us_id);
                            map.put(LV_TEXT, name);
                            map.put(LV_TEXT_CHAT, txt);
                            data.add(map);
                        }

                        String[] from = { LV_USID, LV_TEXT, LV_TEXT_CHAT};
                        int   [] to   = { R.id.us_id, R.id.chatTitleName, R.id.textChat };


                        sAdapter = new ChatAdapter(context, data, R.layout.chat_msg_style, from, to);
                        sList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvChat);
                        sList.setAdapter(sAdapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("chatPrivate", "chatPrivate");
                    hashMap.put("us_id", MainActivity.id);
                    hashMap.put("fr_id", user_id);

                    return hashMap;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(request);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);

            sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //TODO: Тут крах app
            mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.post(new RefreshActivity());
        }

         class RefreshActivity extends Thread {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChatServer.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//TODO: Пробовал и тут
                        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 15000);
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        class ChatAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

            public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to){
                super(context, data, resource, from, to);
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.us_id);

                String userAvaId = textView.getText().toString();
                avatars = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.chatAva);
                Picasso.with(v.getContext())
                        .load("http://mysite/avatars/" + userAvaId + ".jpg")
                        .error(R.drawable.no_avatar)
                        .into(avatars);
                sList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    }
                });
                return v;
            }
        }
    }
```

А вот LOGCAT:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.aseke.login, PID: 30147
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.aseke.login.chat.ChatServer$1MessageLoad.onPostExecute(ChatServer.java:155)
at com.example.aseke.login.chat.ChatServer$1MessageLoad.onPostExecute(ChatServer.java:77)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

У Вас асинхронный вызов в `doInBackground`, в итоге у вас отрабатывает `onPostExecute` до того, как вы получаете ответ от сервера
а это значит, что код в `onResponse` еще не успел отработать, это была первая ошибка...

Вторая - вы обращаетесь к UI потоку в `doInBackground`, тут вы тоже поймаете исключение.

```
 sAdapter = new ChatAdapter(context, data, R.layout.chat_msg_style, from, to);
 sList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvChat);
 sList.setAdapter(sAdapter);
```

По сути вопроса - вам нужен добавить в адаптер метод setData(), в котором вы передадите ваши новые данные.
после чего вызвать `notifyDataSetChanged` у адаптера. 
Для сохранения позиции используйте этот код

```
// сохраните текущую позицию
int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = mList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

// тут вызовите notifyDataSetChanged у вашего адаптера

// восстановите позицию
mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Comment: А можно по подробней про мои ошибки пожалуйста

Comment: Дело в том что я не много не понимаю где именно вызывать notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Был бы очень рад если бы вы показали пример именно в моём скрипте..спасибо за ранее

Comment: Это объемный вопрос ) и точно не для комментария, AsyncTask, а если быть точнее его метод doInBackground работает в отдельном потоке, и по сколько он должен вернуть вам какой то объект, то как минимум все действия в методе doInBackground должны быть синхронными (выполняться в том же потоке). чтобы менять меньше кода, перепишете new StringRequest... к примеру на HttpURLConnection, он выполнит синхронный запрос на сервер. Все остальные действия с UI (список, адаптер) выполняйте после того как будет вызван onPostExecute

Comment: Chaynik, спасибо дружище, помог :)